# Overriding C# Conditional statements problem

Tags: c#, .net

I was writing some code today and something was not working as I expected.

Why does the following code execute even though the condition should have evaluated to false?

[alt text http://img215.imageshack.us/img215/3011/agfewrf.gif](http://img215.imageshack.us/img215/3011/agfewrf.gif)

I have tried putting braces around the two conditions, and switching their position, but the EndedUsingApplication even still executes.

EDIT:

It has nothing to do with the || or && operators. Look at this...

[image]

Nobody can learn from my mistake unless I post the culprit code, so here it is.

```
  public static bool operator ==(ActiveApplication a, ActiveApplication b)
     {
     if ((object)a == null || (object)b == null)
        return false;
     return a.process_name == b.process_name && a.window_title == b.window_title;
     }

  public static bool operator !=(ActiveApplication a, ActiveApplication b)
     {
     return a == b ? false : true;
     }
```

And here is the working code ...

```
  public static bool operator ==(ActiveApplication a, ActiveApplication b)
     {
     // Casting to object class prevents this comparison operator being executed
     // again and causing an infinite loop (which I think .NET detects and stops
     // but it would still be a huge hole in the logic.
     if ((object)a == null && (object)b == null)
        return true;
     if ((object)a == null ^ (object)b == null)
        return false;
     return a.process_name == b.process_name && a.window_title == b.window_title;
     }

  public static bool operator !=(ActiveApplication a, ActiveApplication b)
     {
     return a == b ? false : true;
     }
```

The problem appeared to be when the != operator received two null values.

Comment: @Jay Riggs: Bingo! Yeah it turns out I have. There is some bad logic in there which is returning an incorrect result. Write a proper answer and maybe I'll mark it as the answer ;)

Comment: @Nippy - add as an answer!  Thanks!

Comment: :) - this was like playing 20 questions

Comment: I assume you've got some regression unit tests in there too for that :p

Comment: "a == b ? false : true" is cleaner expressed as "!(a == b)"

Comment: ~more cleanly expressed, that is

Comment: Thats a matter of opinion imho :)

Comment: Did you mean `==` or `object.ReferenceEquals()` ?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Have you overloaded `!=`?

Comment: See the original question for explanation.

Comment: yes, the lesson is if anyone tries to overload an operator, you hit them with a fish.

Comment: Shall we truck in some nice, aged trout from IRC land?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure why.  But are you sure the running application is compiled using the code you are stepping through.  I have seen this sort of thing when the code is different to what is actually being executed.

Answer (score 1):

Is your program multi threaded?

I have seen situations where I check a value and then try using it only to find its changed. Whats happened is that another thread as changed the value after I checked it but before I used it.

Answer (score 1):

Are you certain that you're actually on the line you have highlighted?  You can click around in the call stack window and make any part of the call stack the "current" line in the sense that you can get the value of variables there and so forth.

The point being, perhaps EndedUsingApplication sets ActiveApplication to null, so that ActiveApplication *wasn't* null when it evaluated the if, but *now* it's null when you're evaluating it in the debugger.

Have you put a breakpoint on the EndedUsingApplication(ActiveApplication) line to make sure ActiveApplication is null before you execute that line?

Answer (score 1):

I think a better approach is to use `Object.ReferenceEquals` as it is more explicit:

```
public static bool operator ==(ActiveApplication a, ActiveApplication b)
     {
     // same reference so equals is true - will be true for null == null
     if (object.ReferenceEquals(a, b))
        return true;

     // one is null and the other is not
     if (object.ReferenceEquals(a, null) || object.ReferenceEquals(b, null))
        return false;

     // dealt with all combinations of null - compare fields
     return a.process_name == b.process_name && a.window_title == b.window_title;
     }

  public static bool operator !=(ActiveApplication a, ActiveApplication b)
     {
     return !(a == b);
     }
```